# how to centralize linearlayout with items for all devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="70dp"

    tools:context="com.example.sepia2.myapplication.Main3Activity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/link0"
            android:id="@+id/link0"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:textColor="#e67d0a"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
           />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/link1"
                android:id="@+id/link1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/link2"
                    android:id="@+id/link2"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                   />
</linearlayout>
```

Basically my point is that how can i centralize this layout? what is the accepted approach.

basically what i have done is this (can this approach break down in other screens?)

```
 android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
```

but i have to adjust it. how can it automatically get in the center of the screen across all devices big or small?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set gravity to linear layout

```
android:gravity="Center" //  this will make all child into center of screen
```

and to make LinearLayout to center,

```
android:layout_gravity="Center"
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

Comment: ok but my textviews items''' texts''' also become centralize. can i adjust them with margins?

Comment: yes they become centralize, but you want to show them with full width?

Comment: so to do that you do changes in linear layout by  "android:layout_gravity = center_vertical" and adjust your textview with margin and apply "android:gravity=center_vertical" to textview so text will become center vertically

Answer (score 0):

simply make it `layout_width="wrap_content"` and `layout_gravity="center"`.. hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this blogpost to clarify how `gravity` / `layout_gravity` really works http://sandipchitale.blogspot.ru/2010/05/linearlayout-gravity-and-layoutgravity.html